# JQuery set background of rows of a form / table based on values of two columns

Tags: jquery, css, background, closest

I have a web application with a form with multiple rows showing orders.
I need to color every row based on values of the "fields" 'ordine_cancellato' (italian for deleted order, 1/0 values) and 'factory'.
Both 'fields' gets a css class named css_fieldname_obj , which I use to find the value and set the css background.
If order is deleted the entire row must be set to pink , else depending whether factory is null or not, the entire row must be orange or green.
The code is as following.

$(document).ready(function() {

```
//ORDINE CANCELLATO
$('.css_ordine_cancellato__obj').each(function(){
     if($(this).val() === '1') {
         alert("DELETED ORDER");
         $(this).closest('td').css('backgroundColor','pink');
         $(this).closest('tr').closest('td').css('backgroundColor','pink');
         $(this).closest('tr').closest('td').siblings().css('backgroundColor','pink');
     }
     else if ($(this).closest('.css_factory__obj').val() === '') {
              alert("EMPTY FACTORY");
              $(this).closest('td').css('backgroundColor','orange');
              $(this).closest('tr').closest('td').css('backgroundColor','orange');
              $(this).closest('tr').closest('td').siblings().css('backgroundColor','orange');
     } else {
              alert("FACTORY IS SET");
              $(this).closest('td').css('backgroundColor','green');
              $(this).closest('tr').closest('td').css('backgroundColor','green');
              $(this).closest('tr').closest('td').siblings().css('backgroundColor','green');
     }
});
```

I put an alert for every row, only to test the behaviour.
Deleted orders get pink correctly.
Problem is that any other row gest green (alert FACTORY IS SET), so I guess the if condion

($(this).closest('.css_factory__obj').val() === "")

is wrong .
I know I am doing something stupid at very basic level, but I do not understand what.
What I think the condition should be is : given that this row is not pink, find the value of the factory , if it is not NULL , set orange, else set green.

Insted, every row gest green .
 
Not sure if the error is in the selection of field , or in the equal operation ?

Thanks in advance
Federico

The solution was to traverse right the form , looking exactly at HTML code .

Answer (score 0):

Please provide html code, an option could be the '===' operators compares elements without changing their type, so you could try to be more flexible using the '=='..

Or maybe the

```
$(this).closest('.css_factory__obj').val()
```

isn't returning an empty string instead could be returning " ",a string with an space on it try adding the trim function...

```
$(this).closest('.css_factory__obj').val().trim()
```

Comment: RenzoCC, thanks for reply and sorry for my ignorance about JQuery / css. I think the problem is me not being able to traverse the tags and find the one I am looking for. May I send you an excerpt of the HTML code ?

Comment: Sure, you can also check https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/jquery_ref_selectors.asp to transverse the appropriate element...

Comment: if ($(this).closest('table').closest('TD').siblings().find('.css_factory__obj').val()   was the right selector ... A mess , but it works :-) thanks RenzoCC